# WooCommerce не показывает фото

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Поставил CMS WooCommerce
И столкнулся с такой проблемой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото просто не отображатся.

Выдал права на папку uploads 777, не помогло, при любом стиле wordpress такая проблема.
Пробывал переустанавливать - не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если смотреть через админку эту страницу то все окей

Comment: Если для залогиненного пользователя все ок - то криво настроен плагин кеширования.